# "display: none" with highcharts - incorrect size

Tags: html, css, highcharts, size, display

How to force to work correctly highcharts with display:none style.
If initially the chart was invisible (display: none) after it becomes visible (display: block) -its size is set incorrect.

https://jsfiddle.net/0we2u4qg`example of incorrect chart's size`

How to fix it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang = "ru">

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge" />

    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <style>     
        .info {
            position:           absolute;
            left:               50%;
            top:                50%;

            color:              #f0f0f0;
            font-weight:        700;
            font-size:          24px;
            font-family:        'calibri';
        }

        .chart {
            display:            none;

            position:           absolute;
            left:               50px;
            top:                50px;

            width:              200px;
            height:             200px;

            margin:             0px;
            padding:            0px;

            border:             2px solid #bb0000;
        }

        .chart .container {
            width:              100%;
            height:             100%;

            background-color:   #bbbb00;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class = "info">CLICK ANYWHERE</div>
    <div class = "chart"><div class = "container"></div></div>
<script>

(function ($)
{
    $('.container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories:     [10, 20, 30, 40, 50,],
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation:      false
            },
        },
        series: [
        {
            type:           'column',
            data:           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,],
        },
        {
            type:           'column',
            data:           [5, 4, 3, 2, 1,],
        },
        ]
    });

    $(window).click(function(){
        $('.info').hide();
        $('.chart').show();
    });

}(jQuery));

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know you put up a jsfiddle but please post your code in your question as well so future visitors will be able to learn from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to call `chart.reflow()` after `.show()`, so your chart will adjust to the size of its container.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0we2u4qg/8/

```
...
$('.info').click(function() {
  $('.info').hide();
  $('.chart').show();
  $('#container').highcharts().reflow(); //added call
});
```

Comment: but in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Zhihar/ox1377dj/4/
your method isn't work

only if i set individual "reflow". but it's dirty :)

https://jsfiddle.net/Zhihar/ox1377dj/5/

Comment: @Zhihar Yes, each chart should have `reflow` called - https://jsfiddle.net/9qhjvoya/

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.chart')
        .hide();
});
```

and use `display: block;` in css.